# Mysql where clause using equal is not working, only by using LIKE

Tags: mysql, laravel, where-clause

I have a laravel application that generate and execute the query below

```sql
select
      *
    from
      `read_items`
    where
      `subject_type` = 'App\Models\Scholar'
      and `user_id` = 59;
```

Above sql is not working, although I have the data with `user_id = 59` and `subject_type = 'App\Models\Scholar'` at the same row

But when I use `like`, the query is working

```sql
select
      *
    from
      `read_items`
    where
      `subject_type` like '%Scholar'
      and `user_id` = 59;
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I already make sure that there are no trailing spaces. I'm not sure if indexing on column `subject_type` affect this.

Comment: what does "not working" mean?  giving an error?  not finding the correct rows?  finding incorrect rows?

Comment: @ysth I mean was the expected result is not shown when using `=` but working when using `like`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Backslash `\` is used to escape the very next character. So you have to escape `\` with one more `\`

So your query should be like

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `read_items`
WHERE
    `subject_type` = 'App\\Models\\Scholar' AND `user_id` = 59
```

**Result**

[image]

`But when I use like, the query is working`

Thats because you used only `subject_type like '%Scholar'`. Try with `subject_type  LIKE '%Models\Scholar%'`, it wont work

Comment: @forpas You must escape it. Your fiddle is working because your insert query removes backslash. Just see the result of query. Why it has no backslash ?

Comment: Thanks, it works! I think this is a possible issue in Laravel regarding polymorphic relationships.

Answer (score 1):

Backslash is an escape character in mysql, so you have to double it

```
select
      *
    from
      `read_items`
    where
      `subject_type` = 'App\\Models\\Scholar'
      and `user_id` = 59;
```